# What is this gotcha inRails application.routes.recognize_path when using the root path of a mounted engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I am developing an engine and I need to programmatically find which controller action will be used for any path of either the host app or my engine.  However, there seems to be a gotcha when resolving the root PATH of an engine.

The dummy's routes file is:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Authz::Engine => '/authz', as: :authz
  #...
end
```

The engine's routes file is:

```rb
Authz::Engine.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  resources :foos
   #...
end
```

Somewhere in the main app I am doing the following I don't understand what is the gotcha here...

```rb
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path authz.root_path, method: :get
# => No route matches "/authz"
```

Strangely if I do the following, I get the correct answer.

```rb
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path authz.root_url, method: :get
# => {:controller=>"authz/home", :action=>"index"}
```